# Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS not finding iPhone Hotspot?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, iphone, nmcli

I'm trying to connect to an iPhone 12 Pro Wifi hotspot but nmcli won't even list the SSID. Force connecting to the known SSID obviously also doesn't work. I am able to connect to it using other devices. The server can also connect fine to my standard home network.

I also tried iwlist and it also does not show the iPhone SSID, only home network.

iPhone supposedly supports both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz according to spec. Nevertheless the NUC trying to connect also supports both bands.

Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: there are 2 different WIFI frequency bands that exist: 2.4 GHz, and 5 GHz. It is possible that your iPhone supports one band, and your home wifi supports a different band (or both), and your Ubuntu Server does not support the one that your iPhone has.

Comment: IPhone supports both (it has a ”compability mode” which is 2.4Ghz)

Answer (score 0):

Try loging onto your router to see if devices are on the same network, they might be on different bands (2.4Ghz or 5Ghz) which also might cause problems.

Comment: There is no standalone router. I’m trying to connect to a hotspot which has both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz)

Answer (score 0):

I have turned on „Maximize Compatibility” in the Settings > Hotspot and after that Ubuntu 22 can find the hotspot.